# How to change model owner in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I use Ruby on rails and mongoid.
I have two models User.rb and Project.rb. If I want to change owner of Project model, how should I do this?

User.rb

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String
  has_many :projects, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Project.rb

```
class Project
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :title, type: String

  validates :user_id, presence: true

  belongs_to :user, touch: true
end
```

in form.html.erb i have select mode

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.collection_select :user_id, User.all, :id, :name, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
```

Comment: Did you try something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to just assign it to the user field and then save it to persist it to the database

```
project = Project.find(project_id)
new_owner = User.find(new_owner_id)
project.user = new_owner
project.save
```

Comment: assign it to the user association*

Answer (score 0):

i did not use mongoid long time ago, but you can try running these commands on your `rails console`:

```
project.user = owner_object;
project.save
```

OR

```
project.user_id = owner_id
project.save
```